# Skype for business recording shows a status of Warning

Tags: skype, lync, skype-for-business

For the past 2 days, I am having problems with my recordings done with Skype for business, Windows 10. They show a status of Warning (Runtime Error) and when viewed, I can hear the audio, but the video said nobody was sharing content (though content was presented for both the videos). And the length in the recording manager shows 0:00:00 for some reason.

I have republished it twice, but still no change. The only thing I have done different in the past week which I think may have caused this issue is that I did the recent Windows 10 update that kept popping up on my screen for a long time. I have had no issues with the recordings so far, until yesterday and today.

Does anyone know how to go about fixing this issue?

[Skype recording manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZfGC.png)

Comment: As the office suite (Outlook, Skype for Business, ...) makes use of the hardware acceleration a good option would be to check if your driver and firmware are up to date. We had an issue with Microsoft and involved the support team here and the outcome was an outdated intel graphic driver. Once updated it works fine, so please check if your driver are up to date (but please check them without any bogus 3rd party driver check tool).